# Quartz Scheduler - Cron Trigger expression not working

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler in order to schedule some sequence of functionalities in my java project. I want the scheduler to start at 08:00:00 and to repeat for every four hours till 16:00:00. I have tried doing this using CRONTrigger with below expression:

"0 0 8,12,16 * * ?"

But it is not working fine as expected. Please help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try the next:

```
0 0 8,12,16 ? * *
```

Whit this, [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) show the next sample scheduled dates:

```
1. Wednesday, May 29, 2013  8:00 AM
2. Wednesday, May 29, 2013 12:00 PM
3. Wednesday, May 29, 2013  4:00 PM
4. Thursday,  May 30, 2013  8:00 AM
5. Thursday,  May 30, 2013 12:00 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can visit http://www.cronmaker.com/ in this site you can create your cron expression or test this one. or you can try this `0 0 8,12,16 1/1 * ? *`